# Reinforcement learning with PPO - tips and tricks

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

I am trying to use PPO where the agent has to maneuver around an obstacle towards the target while respecting the spatial boundaries. While the agent learns to respect spatial boundaries it never learns to get around the obstacle to the other side and seems to get stuck on some local minima. I have tried the following : mu (mean) output with a given standard deviation decay, mu and variance/covariance outputs (where variance is a nn parameter in torch and in other setting as a network similar to mu). In addition I have also tried beta distribution. The hyperparameters were tuned using Optuna for each architecture. Have tried different reward functions but no avail, What am I missing?

Comment: Are you learning from pixels? Are you sure you have explored enough? Also are you sampling the action each time or just taking the mean from the distribution?

Comment: Please check if during training the agent reaches the goal. If not then you need to place the agent randomly at the start of each episode. I suspect that the reward is positive only at the goal location and 0 elsewhere. So during training the agent needs to experience the positive reward of the goal location.

Comment: @LucaAnzalone No the environment is a custom python script and I tried sampling with Normal/MultiVariateNormal/beta distributions.

Comment: @Constantinos the agent at times reaches the goal but by going through the obstacle zone (if it gets too close simulation is stopped with big negative reward). Agent start and end positions are randomised at every trial. The rewards are continuous : function of distance to target and distance to obstacle

Comment: @SathukaBootham I think having only the distance as reward is not enough, you need to penalize obstacle zones as well, and maybe also penalize the number of steps.

Comment: Rewards are function of distance to target, distance to obstacle and if it gets too close there is large negative award and terminated, in addition it it gets too close to boundaries as well there is termination and finally its proportional to number of steps (loitering around is okay up to certain time and agent need not reach target asap). As of now beta distribution (based on implementation [link](https://github.com/jsztompka/MultiAgent-PPO/) fares worse compared to normal.

Comment: Having only distance to goal (should be negative as we want to minimize the distance!) as a reward function it will suffice to solve the task. Could you describe a bit the task? What are the values of the reward function?

Comment: The task is obstacle avoidance. Target award is negative and is 1/10 in scale of obstacle award, in addition there are negative awards for violating spatial bounds (same weightage as obstacle award). Different reward functions tried (polynomials with different orders, exponential) but all leads to more or less same outcome - rewards does increase at the beginning and becomes stable. When random simulations performed with learned controller mostly they end up with spatial bounds violations after some time. Very few success where both spatial and obstacle restrictions were observed.